# JSON Data not displayed in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts

I have been trying to display my `JSON` data returned from action class in my `JSP`, but in vain...

I am using `struts 2.1.8`..

The following is the struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"></constant>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources">      </constant>

<package name="sampleStrutapp" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="login" class="struts2.LoginAction">
       <result name="success">/checkValidation.jsp</result>
       <result name="error">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>

<package name="struts2" extends="json-default">

  <action name="populate" class="struts2.Populating">
    <result type="json">
     <param name="root">popdata</param>
     <param name="noCache">true</param>
    </result>

  </action>


</package>

  </struts>
```

My action class is the following..

```
 package struts2;



import java.util.List;



 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.*;

 import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

 import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;

 import data.Details;

 import com.Various_functions;
  public class Populating extends ActionSupport {



/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String usrname;
public String email;
public String lang;
public String gender;
public String comp;
public String desg;
public int rownum;
public int row;
public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public void setRow(int row) {
    this.row = row;
}
private String popdata;

public String getPopdata() {
    return popdata;
}

public void setPopdata(String popdata) {
    this.popdata = popdata;
}

public int getRownum() {
    return rownum;
}

public void setRownum(int rownum) {
    this.rownum = rownum;
}

public String execute(){


Various_functions funct = new Various_functions();

List<Details> dev = funct.populate(this.getRow());



this.popdata = dev.get(0).getCompName()+","+dev.get(0).getDesig()+","+dev.get(0).getEmailId()+","+dev.get(0).getGender()+","+dev.get(0).getLang()+","+dev.get(0).getUserName();



System.out.println("In action class");
return "success";
}

public String getUsrname() {
    return usrname;
}
public void setUsrname(String usrname) {
    this.usrname = usrname;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getLang() {
    return lang;
}
public void setLang(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getComp() {
    return comp;
}
public void setComp(String comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
}
public String getDesg() {
    return desg;
}
public void setDesg(String desg) {
    this.desg = desg;
}



 }
```

and my javascript is the following..

```
 function populate(rownum){

alert(rownum);

var inputData = { "row" : 1
};
//  alert(inp);
$.post('populate.action', inputData, populatecallback, "json");



}


function populatecallback(popdata) {


alert("in call back!!");
var result = popdata.split(",");

 usrname= result[5];
 email= result[2];
 desg= result[1];
 lang= result[4];
 comp= result[0];
 gender= result[3];

 $('#txtName').val(usrname);
 $('#txtEmail').val(email);
 $('#txtCmp').val(comp);
 $('#txtDesg').val(desg);
 $('#lan').val(lang);
 $('#gen').val(gender);




}
```

**Now, the jquery post is not working.**

The following is the current library structure..

commons-collections-3.1.jar,
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar,
commons-io-1.3.2.jar,
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
freemarker-2.3.15.jar,
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar,
slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar,
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar,
struts2-jquery-plugin-1.8.3.jar,
xwork-core-2.1.6.jar

My js files are the following..

jquery-1.6.4.min.js,
json.js

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
hemanth.

Comment: Please list the libraries you're deploying, and their versions-right now it looks like a library mismatch, from the exception.

Comment: antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
xwork-2.1.3.jar
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
jsonplugin-0.34.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
commons-io-2.0.1-javadoc.jar
commons-io-2.0.1-sources.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar

Comment: Hi dave, the above is my list..

Answer (score 1):

Might not be relevant now, but back in 2009, there was an issue with Struts and writing json, namely:

http://code.google.com/p/jsonplugin/issues/detail?id=91

Perhaps its a similar issue you are hitting.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for early response. I had seen the link that you sent , but that was for struts 2.1.7, i am using struts 2.1.8. But either way, do you have any work around for the above issue??

Comment: I noticed - what version of XWorks are you using?  The bug is still open... you could check the source of 2.1.8 and see if it includes the suggested patch.  Presumably upgrading to a more recent version of Struts is not an option?

Comment: chris, i am using the following xwork , xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
xwork-2.1.3.jar.. How to apply the patch in the source of xwork, can u suggest please.

Comment: See Dave's answer - you have mismatched library versions

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by a library version mismatch; in your case you're deploying *multiple* versions of XW, which is even worse. S2.1.8.1 requires xwork-core 2.1.6. Having both on the path is a bad idea. Consider using Maven to handle your dependency management, and avoid these kinds of headaches.

I did not verify the remaining versions on your list; you need to do so. The easiest way is to use Maven, or check against something like mvnrepository.com (where I got the [S2.1.8.1 XW dependency from](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.8.1)).

Comment: Hi dave, I have removed all the multiple matches, but its still giving the same exception..

Comment: @hemanth Please update your question with the currently-deployed libraries. I think Chris's answer is still more on the right track; it looks like the JSON plugin you're using expects an older version of XW? Is there another way you could write the JSON, or can you update S2, etc?

Comment: @hemanth See my second comment--it looks like that's a known issue as Chris stated, with a patch, although it may be easier to write the JSON some other way.

Comment: I have not got any other way to write JSON for my requirement, so far. I thought this was a feasible method, since I had seen it getting implemented elsewhere. can you please suggest?

Comment: Use a different JSON library and write it to the response, use the convention plugin, patch the jsonplugin, try rolling back XW and seeing if it works, ...

Comment: dave, I have found out the problem, I had included json plugin into my directory, once i removed it, the exception was not coming. The reason being struts 2.1.8 already has a json built-in. But, still my issue solution is at large. Now, the jquery post is not working.